# Is there a javascript bookmarklet to play all videos from a given video's channel on Youtube?

Tags: javascript, youtube, bookmarklet

Quite often I fall on a youtube video I like, and am interested in seeing other videos from the same channel. I wanted a bookmarklet to reopen the video page with other videos from the same channel listed on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is!

I figured how to do it, and thought I'd share it:

`javascript:location.href+='&list='+document.querySelector('#owner-name > a').href.replace('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC','UU')`